# What does $C^{\infty}$ represent?

Tags: analysis

I'm reading a paper on multi-resolution analysis and they say, '..consider a set of $C^{\infty}$ functions on $X$..'. Is this infinity differentiable?

Comment: Yes, they mean functions which are infinitely many times differentiable.

Comment: @sranthrop Thanks. Feel free to add that as an answer.

Comment: Your wish is my command :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they mean functions which are infinitely many times differentiable. :)